# IIS Output Cache vs ASP.NET Output Cache

Tags: iis, asp.net, cache

Quote from [iis.net](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/caching): `The ASP.NET page output cache is separate from the IIS 7 output cache. In applications that use the Integrated ASP.NET mode, the ASP.NET page output cache can be used programmatically for any content-type, much like the IIS 7 output cache.`

So when will I chose to use IIS Output Cache and when to prefer ASP.net Output Cache? Also it's not clear what they write that asp.net cache "*can be used for any content-type*"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The IIS Output Cache leverages the ASP.NET Output Cache to cache contents from all types of applications, not just ASP.NET.

If you're coding an ASP.NET application you'll have full control of the ASP.NET Output Cache, with all its detailed settings and what not. On the other hand, if you're building a PHP application, IIS will still provide an Output Cache (leveraging what the .NET framework provides) without you having to touch any .NET code for that.

Recommended reading:

- [Configure IIS Output Cache](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/managing-performance-settings/configure-iis-7-output-caching)
- [Enhance your Apps with the Integrated ASP.NET Pipeline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135973.aspx#S8)
- [ASP.NET Caching and Best Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx)
- [IIS 7.0 Output Caching Walkthrough](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/managing-performance-settings/walkthrough-iis-output-caching)